# Force ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to TLS 1.2 on all connections

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, ssl, tls1.2

I have a WCF service which sends an outgoing request. Currently it is using `SSL 3.0` or `TLS 1.0`.

The service I am sending the request to now only accepts `TLS 1.2`.

I can set the `SecurityProtocolType` just before the request (and for each request), but I would like it to use `TLS 1.2` for all outgoing requests without having to specify it for each request.

This code sets it correctly for the request:

```
<OperationContract(), WebGet(UriTemplate:="...")>
Public Function SomeService()

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType) 3072; // 3072 is TLS 1.2

    // Do request

End Function
```

But I cannot see how to set WCF to use `TLS 1.2` for all requests. I have tried placing the above statement into `Application_Start` and `Application_BeginRequest` in `Global.asax`, but by the time it comes to doing the request, `SecurityProtocol` is back to `SSL3/TLS1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the registry you can apply the following key:
[registry key](https://tls1test.salesforce.com/s/NET40-Enable-TLS-1_2.reg)

This enforces TLS 1.2 at the Windows level of the Transport Layer so you don't need to change any code.

These are the keys changed in the above file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Technically, this doesn't **enforce** 1.2, it just disables SSL3 and _allows_ TLS 1.2 -- it also allows TLS 1.0 and 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the Startup.Auth.cs file.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This worked for us.