# System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - dot net framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, certificate, tls1.2

I am getting below error , i have verified the certificate are installed properly , thumbprint is fine. below is my code.

```
On Running below command from Powershell :
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol it shows as SSL3, TLS
```

I am using Dot Net Framework 4.7.1.

System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

```
web.config :

<httpRuntime requestValidationType="SARQA.NET.BaseCode.NoValidationRequestValidator" 
 maxRequestLength="4096" executionTimeout="180" targetFramework="4.7.1" />

    public static WebRequestHandler getHandlerWithClientCert(string thumbprint)
            {
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                var wrhandler = new WebRequestHandler
                {
                    AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                             System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate
                };

                wrhandler.ClientCertificates.Add(GetCertFromStore(thumbprint));

                return wrhandler;
            }


public static X509Certificate2 GetCertFromStore(string thumbprint)
        {            
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;

            //removing unwanted char from hexadecimal thumbprint
            thumbprint = Regex.Replace(thumbprint, @"[^\da-fA-F]", string.Empty).ToUpper();

#if(DEBUG)
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root,StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
#else
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
#endif
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(
                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true
            );

            if (certCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                cert = certCollection[0];

            }


            store.Close();

            return cert;
        }
```

Comment: So many possible reasons! I suggest [turning on schannel tracing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kevinjustin/2017/11/08/schannel-event-logging/) which will give you much more detailed troubleshooting information.

Comment: @JohnWu : On server i see SSL3, TLS is installed. DO i need to install TLS1.2 to support this or passing from the code is enough as shown above ?

Comment: If running .NET 4.7.1 then you already have TLS 1.2 installed and enabled by default.

Comment: On server TLS1.2 will be installed by default if it has .Net 4.7.1 package installed ?

Comment: The framework just uses operating system features (SChannel) so it is NOT installed. Windows Server supports TLS since 2008 (https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2017/07/20/tls-1-2-support-added-to-windows-server-2008/). .NET supports TLS 1.2 since v.4.0. SChannel can be configured (https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) so it might be disabled. The framework above can also be configured but only use what the system configuration allows (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874187/force-servicepointmanager-securityprotocol-to-tls-1-2-on-all-connections)